# thread safe singleton using enum

Tags: java, singleton

I am not able to understand how Enum can be used for thread safe singleton instantiation. 
So let us say I have a class A which I want to make singleton. How do I do that using Enum ? I came across suggestion like the code below, but not really able to understand. In the below shall I replace INSTANCE with `A singleObj = new A();` ?

Moreover, how exactly should class A look like as in what thing should I take care of there .. for example: making constructor private etc.

```
public enum EasySingleton{
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the below shall I replace INSTANCE with `A singleObj = new A();`?

You don't. You use:

```
EasySingleton instance = EasySingleton.INSTANCE;
```

You write the singleton just like a normal class, with whatever methods you want etc - but no public constructors (which aren't valid in enums anyway).

Comment: Thanks @Jon. But I still didn't get it. So does it mean that enumn EasySingleton itself will be my singleton class ?

Comment: @Walt: Yes, exactly. It's a singleton because there's only one valid value (`INSTANCE`). You can still make it implement interfaces etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Thanks for being patient with me. Needless to say I am a newbie in the  coding world. :)

Comment: Check out [Joshua Bloch's take](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3) on the topic. He's the java guru!

Answer (score 0):

As Jon mentioned you would do the following:

```
EasySingleton instance = EasySingleton.INSTANCE;
instance.doSomething();
```

If you need some further examples, as well as pros/cons to many of the approaches to creating Singleton classes you can visit: http://avaldes.com/creating-a-thread-safe-singleton-class-with-examples/.